# How Model notifies its change to ViewModel in iOS MVVM pattern

Tags: ios, design-patterns, mvvm, model, viewmodel

Most articles about MVVM describe when the model is changed, for example when new data is made available and we need to update the UI, the Model notifies the View Model.

But I don’t get how Model communicate with View Model to notify about its change.

In the code below, I used property observer to bind View and ViewModel. And I know that I can change my Model by assigning new value like `self.person.value.name = name` in ViewModel.

I read a lot of articles about mvvm and think I wrote an appropriate example as follows, but even in this code I cannot get the concept that Model notifies its change to ViewModel. In my code below, does model notifies viewmodel about its change? Can you explain with examples?

```swift
class Observable<T> {
    var value: T {
        didSet {
            self.listener?(value)
        }
    }
    
    var listener: ((T) -> Void)?
   
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    func subscribe(listener: @escaping (T) -> Void) {
        listener(value)
        self.listener = listener
    }
}

struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

struct MyViewModel {
    var person: Observable<Person>
    
    init(person: Person) {
        self.person = Observable(person)
    }
    
    func changePersonName(with name: String) {
        person.value.name = name
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!
    
    let viewModel = MyViewModel(person: Person(name: “Mike“, age: 100))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        viewModel.person.subscribe { [weak self] person in
            self?.infoLabel.text = person.name + “& " + "\(person.age)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: “does model [notify] viewmodel about its change?” … That’s not how I’d phrase it. The view model has an observable model object and your view has subscribed to changes, thereby binding the view to this model object. The idea of MVVM is that after the binding/subscribing/observing is done, changes in the model object are automatically reflected in the UI (and, in the case of editable UI controls, vice versa).

Comment: If you are looking for examples, I’d refer you to the various articles on the topic, e.g., https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52

Comment: @Rob, Yes I read that article but then why MVVM architecture image in that article uses the word "notifies" between Model and ViewModel? Does that mean nothing?

Comment: There are so many variations on the theme that I wouldn't suggest getting too hung up that label in that graph. In your example, you've made `Person` observable value type, which achieves the same thing. And when `Person` changes, the view subscribes to the observable object, listening for changes.

Comment: BTW, the above is half of the solution. You've got the view subscribing to changes in the `Person`. But in MVVM, you would also do the converse, where, if you had a text field, the `Person` would be validated and updated as you edit the text. FWIW, if you really want to get your arms around this, I think that Bart Jacobs does a good job diving into these details really well (requires subscription?) at https://cocoacasts.com/categories/model-view-viewmodel. He walks through all sorts of issues, implementations in different frameworks, etc.